# Does compilers move skip checks to outside the function call?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

Functions or methods like:

```
void DoSomething(...){

  if( ... ) return;

  ...
}
```

Checks that skip the entire function if a condition is met. Does the compiler move the check code outside the function/method to avoid an useless function call?

Comment: Probably not, considering a function can be called in a hundred different locations. These "skip checks" would have to be inserted into each of these locations. And the cost of a function call depends heavily on the passed arguments.

Comment: As far as I know the `if()` will not be moved outside. Can you explain why you are interested in this?

Comment: If the `if` always evaluates to true (in some compile-time determinable way) then the reset of the function could be optimized away, but if that was the case you'd probably see a compiler warning telling you that the `if` was always true

Comment: Most compiler optimizers will inline a function in whole, not just parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler. With gcc on -O3 the call gets ignored.

To try it I wrote:

```
int g;                                       

int dosomething(int x) {                     
    if (x == 0) return g;                    

    int y = 0;                               
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)              
        y += i;                              
    return y;                                
}                                            

int docall() {                               
    return dosomething(0);                   
}
```

(there's a global to be sure that the last call is not trivialized by
optimization) compiling with -s but without O flags I get this in the assembler:

```
_Z6docallv:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %edi
    call    _Z11dosomethingi
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
```

there's a full fledged call to dosomething with 0 as argument, whereas with -O3 I get:

```
_Z6docallv:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    g(%rip), %eax
    ret
```

so it returns the default value of dosomething without calling it.

Comment: If you change the argument to another value than 0, it still won't insert a function call. So it doesn't move the if outside the function - it simply inlines (and then constant-folds and dead-code-removes) the entire function.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was what the question was about. But you are right, it was about moving the check at call point. And yes there's nothing like that.

Answer (score -2):

If the `if` condition is met, then the return statement will execute and the rest of the function is skipped.
If not , then the rest of the function body is executed (depending on the body).

Comment: Did you read the question?  Did you understand what is being asked?  Because your answer does not address the question at all.